# Passing loop variable to BASH find -regex argument?

Tags: regex, bash, loops, find, arguments

I am trying to copy images selected by a REGEX expression via `find`. The command below runs but does not copy the files. How can I pass a loop variable (e.g. reading lines of a file) to the find -regex argument?

```
cat hit_images_regex_list.txt | while read line; 
do 
find . -regex "${line}" -exec cp --parents {} /destination_dir \;
done
```

The `hit_images_regex_list.txt` file where I am pulling REGEX expressions from looks like this:

```
".*B - 12.*tif"
".*D - 09.*tif"
".*G - 03.*tif"
".*G - 12.*tif"
...
```

Using `find` with each of these REGEX expressions works, but the loop pulling REGEX expressions from my .txt file doesn't do anything.

Comment: The problem is the quotes in the file; they aren't intended to be part of the regular expression. You should just remove them from the file.

Comment: Don't I need to have the quotes to protect the whitespace around the dash?

Comment: No; that's what the quotes in the command line are for, `-regex "$line"` vs `-regex $line`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I made an adjustment to the REGEX file. The problem I was having was that the .txt file was created on Windows and had incorrect end-of-line markers. I used `dos2unix` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(cat hit_images_regex_list.txt); do find -name "$i" | cat -n | while read n f; do cp "$f" /newfolder/path/"$n".tig; done; done
```

this should open the file and for each regex (line) find all files that match and copy to a new folder

does this help

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  find . -regex "$line" -exec cp --parents {} /destination_dir \;
done < hit_images_regex_list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

People have taken time to try and help. Please our of politeness rate the replies